# Brackets xdebug PHP XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug, brackets

Hi i have installed XAMPP and i have put php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14.dll into:
c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14.dll
Then i have opened Brackets and i have installed PHP Debugger, then i have edited c:\xampp\php\php.ini and at the end of file i have added:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14.dll"
xdebug.enable = On
xdebug.idekey=idekey
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%p"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

Then i have stopped Apache and i have added a breakpoint into editor Brackets near a variable $var = 10. Then i have started Apache i have refreshed the page but debug didn't start (or didn't work) why?

Then I have try this:
I have php 7.1.10 and i have downloaded php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14.dll and i have put this in xampp/php/ext. Then i have edit php.ini and i have put at the end of file this:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "c:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14.dll"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_log="c:\xampp\tmp\xdebug.txt"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "c:\xampp\tmp"
; 3600 (1 hour), 36000 = 10h
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 36000
```

Then i have changed output_buffering = 4096 to output_buffering = Off.
Finally i have stopped and start Apache but didn't work, why?

Comment: Have you tried this setup? https://gist.github.com/odan/1abe76d373a9cbb15bed

Comment: Yes I have tried...

Comment: But your configuration looks different. Have you tried copy&paste?

Comment: I have already tried the solution that you have posted above but doesn't work...

Comment: Please check the setup from Daniel O above - you should notice that you are missing (at least) the 4 `xdebug.remote...` entries.

Comment: I have tried but don't work, read above, why?

Comment: Did you restart apache? Did you disable output buffering: output_buffering = Off ? Did you started the browser xdebug session with the PhpStorm bookmark? https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/

Comment: I have solved, I am using phpstorm and xdebug work, while with brackets don't work.